# How do I store a bundle in a database blob?

Tags: android, database, bundle

Ive been searching google for a way to convert a `bundle` into a string suitable to store in a database as a `BLOB` type.  I have found lots of examples of serializing it to a file but no mention of how to put it into a string or byte aray.  Can anyone give me an example of how this is done?

I am developing an app that will use plugin's for custom UI components and want to call a configuration activity in the plugin passing a bundle of configuration options that were stored in a database.  The activity would return the bundle with the updated options and then I need to save it back to the database.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is to create a table to put this in. In this case something basic should do.

```
CREATE TABLE bundles (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    name TEXT, 
    value BLOB);
```

Then you will need a method for inserting the `Bundle`, like this:

```
private void put(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, Bundle bundle) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream valueStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ContentValues rows = new ContentValues();
        rows.put("name", name);
        Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
        bundle.writeToParcel(p, 0);

        valueStream.write(p.marshall());
        rows.put("value", valueStream.toByteArray());

        db.insert("bundles", null, rows);   

        valueStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        Log.e("error writing object", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to try this out.  I didn't come across ByteArrayOutputStream in my searches.

Comment: @cstrutton This might not be a perfect solution yet. I'm not sure Bundle is serializable. This might need tweaking. I'm researching more now.

Comment: @cstrutton give my updated code a try. I haven't tested it but it *should* work.

Comment: please give the code for the reverse process. How to get the bundle back from database.

Comment: This is not a good solution, since as explained in documentation, "The data you retrieve here must not be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc). For that, you should use standard serialization or another kind of general serialization mechanism. The Parcel marshalled representation is highly optimized for local IPC, and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data created in different versions of the platform." see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#marshall()